# Como revocar privilegios a usuario en mysql estando en sesión

Tags: mysql, sql

quisiera saber si hay manera de revocar ciertos privilegios a un usuario de mysql estando en sesión.
Por ejemplo el usuario 'anonimo' este conectado a mi servidor y yo como root le revoque el privilegio de **INSERT**

se que el comando para revocar es este...

```
REVOKE INSERT ON *.* FROM 'anonimo'@'%';
```

Pero quiero que ese privilegio se le quite estando en sesión porque ya he aplicado ese comando y he actualizado privilegios con el

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Y aun asi sigue insertando datos, hasta que vuelvo iniciar sesión con el usuario ya me revoca el privilegio, pero quisiera saber si existe la manera de revocarlo en instante que el usuario este en sesión.

Comment: saludos, podrias hacer el cambio, usar SHOW PROCESSLIST;  para validar si hay procesos con ese usuario, detenerlos con el comando kill.

Comment: Hola, ya use ese comando y en efecto detiene la conexión pero lo que quiero es solo revocar ciertos privilegios sin que se tenga que finalizar la sesión por completo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo al [mysql tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-revoke.aspx):

> ## When the MySQL REVOKE command takes effect
>
> The effect of MySQL REVOKE statement depends on the privilege level as follows:
>
> - The changes that are made to the global privileges only take effect when the client connects to the MySQL in the subsequent sessions. The changes are not applied to all currently connected users.
> - The changes of the database privileges are applied after the next `USE` statement.
> - The changes of table and column privilege are applied to all queries issued after the changes were made.

Mi traducción libre sería:

## ¿Cuándo toman efecto los comandos REVOKE de MySQL?

La aplicación de la sentencia REVOKE depende del nivel de privilegio del permiso que se revoca, de acuerdo a:

- Los cambios realizados a privilegios globales toman efecto solamente cuando el cliente se conecta a MySQL en sesiones sub-siguientes. Los cambios no se aplican a los usuarios conectados actualmente.
- Los cambios a los privilegios a nivel de base de datos son aplicados después del siguiente uso de la cláusula `use`.
- Los cambios a privilegios a nivel de tabla y columna son aplicados a todos los queries que son enviados después de realizado el cambio de privilegio.

Entonces, si quieres que los cambios tengan efecto de manera inmediata, te sugiero cambiar de estrategia y dar privilegios específicos.

```
grant insert on BaseDeDatos.Tabla to 'usuario'@'localhost';
```

Te permitiría revocar dicho privilegio y que se aplique desde el siguiente *query* lanzado por el usuario, incluso si está conectado:

```
revoke insert on BaseDeDatos.Tabla from 'usuario'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 2):

Estuve consultando un poco y creo que esa es la mejor forma de hacerlo para revocar los permisos de ***INSERT***, sin embargo existen ***TRIGGERS*** que son disparadores que se ejecutan luego de una acción, entonces pensaría que para este ejemplo se puede utilizar.

Esta es la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) de MySQL, puedes investigar un poco y revisar si te sirve.